# The browser router is not working and gives the output as empty

Tags: reactjs

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './Components/Header';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Header />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>  
  );
}
```

I wanted to display the contents on the Header page, but when it's wrapped in the BrowserRouter tag it gives the output as empty in the webpage. When it's not wrapped the content if the page displays. I have updated the react-router-dom to it's latest version.

Comment: are you on 6.4.3 version for react-router-dom ? If so it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

I think you might actually be using **react-router-dom@6**. The **Switch** component was replaced by a **Routes** component and the **Route** component API changed significantly.

Example:

```
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function App() {
  return (
     <Routes>
       <Router path="/" element={<Home />} />
       ... other routes ...
     </Routes>
  );
}
```

Refer [this link](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/overview)